# Unexpected end of input error while calling javascript function on click of a link in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my code for the HTML file which i am displaying :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
     href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<title>CodeConfig</title>
<style>
.btn-primary-spacing 
{
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>CodeConfig Keys</h2>
  <br>
  <div id="key-buttons">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function linkClickFunc(item,key)
{
  console.log("trying");
  console.log(item + key);
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    CodeConfigkeys = {"ENV": ["Subhayan", "Mary"], "DB_PARAMS": ["SQL_CONNECTIONS_DB", "SQL_CONNECTIONS_COLLECTION"]};
    var html_str = "";
    $.each( CodeConfigkeys, function( key, value ){
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"btn-group dropdown\">";
    html_str = html_str + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-primary-spacing\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" id=\"" + "CodeConfigMenus" + "\">" + key;
    html_str = html_str + "</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>";
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
    submenus = value;
    console.log(submenus);
    value.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        //html_str = html_str + "<li><a href=\"#\">" + item + "</a></li>";
        html_str = html_str + "<li><a href=\"javascript:linkClickFunc(\"" + item + "\",\"" + key + "\");\">" + item + "</a></li>";
    });
    html_str = html_str + "</div></div>";

    });
    //console.log(html_str);
    $("#key-buttons").html(html_str);

});
```

However when i click on any one link in the dropdown menu it comes up with a syntax error saying unexpected end of input.

I guess i am missing some brackets , but i don't seem to find anything as such

Can someone please say where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `javascript:` from `<a href=\"javascript:linkClickFunc(\"" + it` and it works just fine.

Also, change `<a href=\"javascript:linkClickFunc(\"" + item + "\",\"" + key + "\");\">` to `<a onclick=\"linkClickFunc('" + item + "','" + key + "');\">"`

Problem is that your href would look like `href="linkClickFunc("item","item")"` as you can see then you would have the problem with too many `"`

**demo**

```js
function linkClickFunc(item, key) {
  console.log("trying");
  console.log(item + key);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  CodeConfigkeys = {
    "ENV": ["Subhayan", "Mary"],
    "DB_PARAMS": ["SQL_CONNECTIONS_DB", "SQL_CONNECTIONS_COLLECTION"]
  };
  var html_str = "";
  $.each(CodeConfigkeys, function(key, value) {
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"btn-group dropdown\">";
    html_str = html_str + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-primary-spacing\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" id=\"" + "CodeConfigMenus" + "\">" + key;
    html_str = html_str + "</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>";
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
    submenus = value;
    value.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
      //html_str = html_str + "<li><a href=\"#\">" + item + "</a></li>";
      html_str = html_str + "<li><a onclick=\"linkClickFunc('" + item + "','" + key + "');\">" + item + "</a></li>";
    });
    html_str = html_str + "</div></div>";

  });
  $("#key-buttons").html(html_str);

});
```

```css
.btn-primary-spacing {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>CodeConfig Keys</h2>
  <br>
  <div id="key-buttons">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not close the script tag `</script>` **AND** you have to add Jquery to your website:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**AND** delete `javascript:` from `href`:

```
 html_str = html_str + "<li><a href=\"linkClickFunc(\"" + item + "\",\"" + key + "\");\">" + item + "</a></li>";
```

**HERE is work one:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
     href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<title>CodeConfig</title>
<style>
.btn-primary-spacing 
{
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>CodeConfig Keys</h2>
  <br>
  <div id="key-buttons">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function linkClickFunc(item,key)
{
  console.log("trying");
  console.log(item + key);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    CodeConfigkeys = {"ENV": ["Subhayan", "Mary"], "DB_PARAMS": ["SQL_CONNECTIONS_DB", "SQL_CONNECTIONS_COLLECTION"]};
    var html_str = "";
    $.each( CodeConfigkeys, function( key, value ){
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"btn-group dropdown\">";
    html_str = html_str + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-primary-spacing\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" id=\"" + "CodeConfigMenus" + "\">" + key;
    html_str = html_str + "</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>";
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
    submenus = value;
    value.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        //html_str = html_str + "<li><a href=\"#\">" + item + "</a></li>";
        html_str = html_str + "<li><a href=\"linkClickFunc(\"" + item + "\",\"" + key + "\");\">" + item + "</a></li>";
    });
    html_str = html_str + "</div></div>";

    });
    $("#key-buttons").html(html_str);

});
</script>
```